# Invoking observables with Subject next() not working

Tags: rxjs

Why does this function only work once? I click a button to call the next() on the Subject queue which works but if I click the other button it doesn't work.

```
  getData(text): Observable<string> {
    const timer$ = timer(2000);

    const observable = new Observable<string>(observer => {

      timer$.pipe(
        map(() => {
          observer.next('http response ' + text);
        })
      ).subscribe();

    });
    return observable;
  }
```

I setup a Subject and use next() which should make the observable emit data.

```
  queue = new Subject();
  streamA$: Observable<string>;
  streamB$: Observable<string>;
  images$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private timerService: TimerService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.streamA$ = this.timerService.getData('a');
    this.streamB$ = this.timerService.getData('b');
    this.images$ = this.queue.pipe(concatMap((data: string) => data));
  }

  clickA() {
    this.queue.next(this.streamA$);
  }

  clickB() {
    this.queue.next(this.streamB$);
  }
```

Template:

```
<button (click)="clickA()">Click A</button>
<button (click)="clickB()">Click B</button>
<div>{{images$ | async}}</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-queue

Comment: You're pushing an observable of a string, that doesn't really make sense.

Comment: just learning rxjs observable so something to test out operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `concatMap()`. This emits all the events emitted from the first observable emitted by the subject, then all the events emitted by the second observable emitted by the subject.

But the first observable never completes, so there's no way for the second observable to ever emit anything.

If you want the observable returned by the service to emit once after 2 seconds then complete, all you need is

```
return timer(2000).pipe(
  map(() => 'http response ' + text)
);
```

Comment: ok so it's because I didn't use complete() in the observable creation