# Rxjs - How to get observables queued by concatMap?

Tags: rxjs

I am using a Subject to handle 2 observables with a queue, is it possible to get a list of observable events queued up by concatMap?

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.streamA$ = this.streamService.getStream(1);
    this.streamB$ = this.streamService.getSlowStream(2);
    this.images$ = this.queue.pipe(concatMap((res: string) => {
      console.log(res);
      return res;
    }));
 }

 clickA() {
    this.queue.next(this.streamA$);
 }

 clickB() {
    this.queue.next(this.streamB$);
 }
```

Comment: How is that question different from the one you asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521478/invoking-observables-with-subject-next-not-working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invoking observables with Subject next() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521478/invoking-observables-with-subject-next-not-working)

Comment: That questions asks why it wasn't working, why the observables didn't emit events, this is asking for a set of observables. It's the same code different question.

Comment: I'd like to know if rxjs has something for this

Comment: Something for what? In your other question, I explained how to have the events emitted. The events emitted by the two observables are thus queued. So, what is the issue?

Comment: You could always use a `tap` before _and_ after the `concatMap` to store values going in and removing them when they come out.

Comment: I want the event though, I know how to add the value but not the event which I want to be able to cancel

Comment: Why you want to get the list of observable, if they are executing one by one

Comment: i don't understand why being an observable executing one at a time is a reason not to add them to a list